# Dreamweaver Spry Menu2 widget not working

Tags: drop-down-menu, dreamweaver, spry

apologies if this has been covered but I have searched for an answer on the internet.
I need to create a spry menu in dreamweaver. First I used sprymenu 1, but found that it didn't work on an ipad. So then I was directed to the SpryMenu2 widget.

My problem is that when I try to upload this onto my server I keep getting the error message 'SpryMenu.js requires SpryWidget.js!' I have checked, and these files are all uploaded.

Question: how do I fix this error, OR is there an alternative to create a spry-type menu that will work on an ipad?

many thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

I've recently encountered this. Make sure the file size of SpryWidget.js is the same size as the on in dreamweaver.

I first uploaded with Filezilla and got this error. Then I tried DW upload and still got the error. Lastly, I went directly to GoDaddy's FTP file manager and uploaded and it fixed the problem. For some reason it was being changed when uploading on DW or FZ. Now if I can only find out why mine won't work on mobile...

Best of luck